# Creating a map of all coordinate-tagged articles in my own mediawiki

Tags: php, maps, coordinates, mediawiki, kml

i'm looking for a convenient way to create a map of all articles within my mediaWiki and display it via Google Maps or Open Street Map. Currently i am using [Template:Coordinate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aCoordinate) from Wikipedia to tag articles.

I've seen that Wikipedia does map creation via templates like [Template:GeoGroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aGeoGroupTemplate). At least in the german version i figured out that they are doing this by having the toolserver lookup the coords from wikipedia.

I followed this approach but since i'm new to mediaWiki, i couldn't figure out how to use their Toolserver for myself.

A second approach i thought about was creating a KML-File on the fly using the extension KMLExport and pass it to Google Maps, which is possible by providing a url of the file.

Problem here: The extension won't create any valid XML output, instead i receive an error:

```
Call to undefined function wfOpenElement() in mediawiki\extensions\KMLExport\KMLClasses.php
```

Which i think has to do with an old php version used, since the project is discontinued (latest version 2008-10-19).

I've been an application programmer for the last few years using C and many of its derivates, so php isn't my time to shine. My guess could be completely wrong.

I appreciate any help on how to create and link to a map with a layer containing locations of articles in a custom mediaWiki.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for but we (Wikia) have a map view of all tagged articles implemented as an extension.

Here's a link to the page displayed on a wiki:
http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Places

Click on a pin to go to a tagged article (we're using a parser hook to do the tagging).

And here's the source code (GPL-licensed): http://trac.wikia-code.com/browser/wikia/trunk/extensions/wikia/Places

The `WikiaApiPlaces` class might give you what you need. Good luck. :)

Comment: I've already implemented what i wanted with [Semantic MediaWiki](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki) and [Semantic Maps](http://mapping.referata.com/wiki/Semantic_Maps) which does exactly the job for things like your link :) thanks anyway, always good to have additional resources

Comment: Something worth mentioning: I had to downgrade MediaWiki, resulting the following configuration: `MediaWiki 1.17.0  Maps 1.0.1
Semantic MediaWiki 1.6.1
Semantic Maps 1.0.1
Validator 0.4.10`

Answer (score 1):

The [Cargo extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cargo) can do this. You'd set up a template with a Coordinates field, and then use one of the [maps display formats](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cargo/Display_formats#Maps) to display the map.